# Why bother learning Git when I can use GitHub desktop interface?

Tags: git, github

This is a noob question so treat with patience please:
I just started using Git, and cannot figure out why should I bother learning the bits and bytes of Git when I can use the GitHub desktop interface?
It's much faster and more intuitive. And all in all, Git is only a version control environment.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Intuition != understanding. Using a GUI without knowing enough about how Git works is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: One reason is when you work on linux or use git bash on windows, it's much quicker & powerful to use terminal,  another reason is it's more fun, it's your choice.

Comment: When you are using the [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/) or [GitHub for Mac](https://mac.github.com/) desktop applications, you *are* using Git (the distributed version control system). Are you asking about why to use `git`, Git's default command line interface?

Comment: You should learn to use the git command line interface for the same reason that you learn SQL to talk to databases even if GUI frontends exist.

Comment: Being acknoledged is enough reason.

Answer (score 8):

By "GitHub Desktop Interface" I assume you mean "GitHub for Windows".
GitHub for Windows can't do everything that command-line Git can. It is just a UI around the most common Git commands. For example, last time I used it, you couldn't stash, cherrypick merge, commit amend, manage remotes, etc.

That would be my argument for learning at least some Git command line. Though I do agree that for seeing a diff of what files has changed, or selecting only a few files to commit with checkboxes, a UI tool can be easier (I frequently use SourceTree to visually review changes, and the command line for checkouts, branching, merging, etc).

If by "bits and bytes of Git" you actually mean understanding how the files, blobs and trees work inside the .git folder, then I suppose you don't really *need* to know that stuff, but to me it is a lot like asking "why do I need to know how a combustion engine works when all I have to do is turn the key?"
Some of us just really like to know how stuff works...
I mean, I learned assembly and memory addressing in college, but that doesn't really apply to high-level languages directly. However, it does help understand at a fundamental level what is going on internally when you need to do heavy problem solving.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.. I like using the console for git commits and pushes. It's way faster.

`git status`   shows you what has changed.

```
git add filename
git add -a
```

adds specific files or everything that has changed to the commit.

`git commit -m "message here"` lets you set a commit message.
`git push` pushes it to the server.

If you quickly want to commit all your changes locally, you can simply do

```
git commit -a -m "I changed this"
```

and the commit is done. You can reuse this command on the terminal/console by pressing the arrow-up key. So all you have to change is the commit message. You could also push at the same time:

```
git commit -a -m "I changed this" && git push
```

For merging etc. a desktop app is better I think. But you can use both at the same time.

Comment: For merging there is `git mergetool`.