# What are the advantages and differences of using github desktop and using git?

Tags: git, github-desktop

I learned a bit about Git and Github.

Can you tell the advantages of using git compared to Github Desktop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why bother learning Git when I can use GitHub desktop interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646430/why-bother-learning-git-when-i-can-use-github-desktop-interface)

Comment: ...or maybe this one that addresses the underlying confusion: [Difference between Git and GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13321556/2745495)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GitHub Desktop** is a **graphical client** for the GitHub software development platform, which **uses Git** version control.  The desktop client offers essential functions and a tidy display.

**Git** is a free and **open source distributed version control system** designed to handle everything from small to very large projects with speed and efficiency.

So GitHub Desktop **based on git** and shows the results graphical. Git is a technology for version control system and can be used differently. Here are all [GUI Client](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows) where you can use for git (also github).

Answer (score 1):

I understand the confusion. "Git" is actually an open source software that is used to manage source code for projects. "Github" is an online application of this, where the source code is stored and managed online. The "Github Desktop Client" is just one of the many ways to use the technology in Git with Github. The advantage of using Github comes down to it being a bigger platform, and that it is online, both of which may or may not be selling points for you depending on the usecase.